# Help reading opamp datasheet

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm using the op295GP opamp. In the datasheet on the 1st page it's says it has a wide single supply operating range 3 to 36v. What's the difference between the supply voltage ( pg5) and the single supply operating range 3 to 36v?

http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/663089.pdf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would have preferred that they wouldn't say 36 V on the front page. That 36 V is Absolute Maximum Ratings (AMR).

> Stresses above those listed under Absolute Maximum Ratings **may cause permanent damage to the device**. This is a stress rating only; functional operation of the device at these or any other conditions above those indicated in the operational section of this specification is not implied. **Exposure to absolute maximum rating conditions for extended periods may affect device reliability.**  *(page 5)*

You should never operate a device continuously at AMR. For typical power supply values you have to check Electrical characteristics on pages 3 and 4. The information is a bit hidden, but you'll find that most parameters are given under +/-15 V power supply. Stick to that, and forget you ever saw 36 V.

By the way, the 36 V is the same as +/-18 V. That's because an opamp doesn't know the concept ground, it only knows V+ and V-, and the difference between those. If you would look a an opamp's schematic, you won't find any net that's ground, as half-way between V+ and V-.

So, maximum 30 V single supply, or +/-15 V dual supply.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you can either have the +rail be 3 to 36V, and the -rail be GND, or you have positive and negative voltage rails, such as 10+/10-. You need more hardware to generate a second (negative) voltage rail, so having a single voltage supply op amp has plenty of uses.